# How to print the error of termination of Accessibility Service in logcat?

Tags: android, android-studio, accessibilityservice, accessibility-api

I have an accessibility service setup in my app. Whenever I close/kill the app from the apps drawer the accessibility service should ideally run in the background but this doesn't happen. Instead the accessibility service terminates immediately after the app is closed and in the accessibility service manager of the android, it shows "This service is not working properly". Am I missing something in the logcat provided by Android Studio IDE itself ?

What I tried is printing the some stuff in the "onUnbind()" method, but its not getting printed in the logcat. I just want to know exactly what is causing the accessibility service to terminate/crash as soon as I kill the app from apps drawer. Also each time I close the app the service doesn't goes "off" it stops working properly.

Comment: Please, share some code related to the event and error.

Comment: @Rafael Moreira That itself is a problem, I don't even know what is causing the error :(. The logcat is not throwing any error. As soon as the app is killed from apps drawer, the logcat also disconnects itself from apps process. I tried putting try and catch blocks in my service class but that too doesn't work

Comment: Share the accessibility code and the drawer code, let's see.

Comment: @RafaelMoreira I am trying to build an app that continuously monitors the "urls". For the same I am following [link](https://github.com/venkymani/LogUrl/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/midagepro/logurl/LogUrlService.java) this already available code on GitHub. I haven't made any changes to it and I looked for errors in the code too but it they simply doesn't seem to exist